# SQL Conditional select - calculate running total

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that calculates requirements for customers based on input that we receive from them.

Displaying this information is not a problem.

What I'd like to do is show the most recent received amount and subtract that from the weekly requirements.

So if last Friday I shipped 150 items and this weeks requirements are 100 items for each day then I'd like the data grid to show 0 for Monday, 50 for Tuesday, 100 for Wednesday - Friday.

I have currently tried using with limited success the sample select statement -

```
Select Customer, PartNumber, LastReceivedQty, Day1Qty, Day2Qty, Day3Qty, Day4Qty, Day5Qty,
TotalRequired
FROM Requirements
```

Obviously the above select statement does nothing but display data as it is in the table.  So when I add the case state as follows I get a bit closer to what I need but not fully and I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
Select Customer, PartNumber, LastReceivedQty, 
"Day1Qty" = case When Day1Qty > 0 then Day1Qty - LastReceivedQty end
...
```

This method works ok as long as the LastReceivedQty is less than the Day1 requirements but it's incorrect because it allows a negative number to be displayed in day one rather than pulling the remainder from day2.

Sample Data looks like the following:

```
Customer    PartNumber  LastReceivedQty Day1Qty Day2Qty Day3Qty Day4Qty Day5Qty TotalRqd

45Bi          2526            150          -50     100     100     100
```

In the sample above the requirements for part number 2526 Day 1 are 100 and the last received qty is 150
The day1qty shows -50 as opposed to zeroing out day 1 and subtract from day2, 3, etc.

How do I display those figures without showing a negative balance on the requirement dates?

Any help/suggestions on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide an example schema, data, and the query you tried? It will help improve the quality of responses

Comment: Please include sample data and desired result. That's way easier to understand and more important, easier to answer, since we can just write a query for you and don't have to come up with data for ourselfes, which might not be exactly what you want and so on. Help us help you!

Comment: Which RDBMS and which version?  Recent editions of Oracle and SQL Server allow using the `OVER()` clause like `SUM(<Field>) OVER(PARTITION BY <Fields> ORDER BY <Fields> ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`

Comment: Sorry,  MSSQL 2008r2